# View SSRS reports in SharePoint 2007 and prevent caching

Tags: sharepoint, ssrs-2008

Our SharePoint 2007 system currently does not have any SSRS Web parts available.
The problem is that when using a Web Viewer Part, reports are being cached by the
page. I cannot remember if the SSRS Web Parts have a no-caching setting and
which web parts should be installed to veiw reports on a SharePoint page.

I found several possibilities on Microsofts web sites, but I would like to know
if anyone has had success installing the web parts on MOSS 2007 and exacly which
web parts you did use. I know you can download the old SSRS 2005 web parts and I
believe that they work on MOSS 2007. But would the SharePoint SSRS Add-ins solve
the problem? The system is not currently set up to use SSRS Integration and this is not an option.

Thanks in advance,
doug

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direct step by step explanation of what you may need to do:

http://mosshowto.blogspot.com/2009/02/reporting-services-2008-report.html

Note that you can do this on your existing Sharepoint site with no issues at all- it's just an add-in, once you install/configure it, you should be able to add the web parts necessary as explained above.

I hope this helps!